# Evaluating user input using StringTokenizer while utilizing custom checked exceptions

Tags: java, exception, stringtokenizer

I've been working on a java project for the last couple days, and while things have gone smoothly to this point, I have hit a bit of a snag.

The point of the project is to create a query of sorts, where the user searches for a report using a GUI interface and the app spits out all related data.

Ex: report all where quality > 3

I use a StringTokenizer object to break the String down and evaluate each token. The first token MUST be **report**, the second token MUST be **all**, third token MUST be **where**, the fourth token MUST be either **quality**, **basePrice** or **numInStock**, the fifth token MUST be a relational operator(**> <** **<= >= ==**). We were instructed to throw custom checked exceptions if any of the tokens do not match what they should be. So far I have evaluated each token, and `throw` an `Exception` if the expected token is not what it should be.

Now once I reach the relational operator, i'm supposed to dump it into a new `String` called `optok`. The problem is, I can't seem to get my program to do this and i'm having a hard time figuring out how to do so. I've tried many different things and nothing seems to work.

The final goal is, once all the tokens have been evaluated and checked, to call a method to print the correct query and all data that goes along with said query. If one of the tokens doesn't match, an `Exception` is `thrown`.

Here is my code for evaluating each token, to check that it is in the correct format:

```
public void detectUserInput(String input) throws MissingInputException
    {
        if (input.equals(""))
        {
            System.out.println("Null input");
            throw new MissingInputException();
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Input is not null");
        }

    }//end detectUserInput 

    public void countTokens(String input) throws IncorrectFormatException
    {
        StringTokenizer tokenLength = new StringTokenizer(input, " ,");

        if (tokenLength.countTokens() < 6)
        {
            throw new IncorrectFormatException();
        }
    }//end countTokens

    public void evaluateTokens(String input) throws IllegalStartOfQueryException,
                                                    InvalidSelectorException,
                                                     InvalidQualifierException,
                                                      InvalidLValueException,
                                                       InvalidOperatorException
    {
        StringTokenizer testTokens = new StringTokenizer(input, " ,");

        if (!testTokens.nextToken().equalsIgnoreCase("report"))
        {
            throw new IllegalStartOfQueryException();
        }
        else if (!testTokens.nextToken().equalsIgnoreCase("all"))
        {
            throw new InvalidSelectorException();
        }
        else if (!testTokens.nextToken().equalsIgnoreCase("where"))
        {
            throw new InvalidQualifierException();
        }
        else if (!testTokens.nextToken().matches("quality|numInStock|basePrice"))
        {
            throw new InvalidLValueException();
        }
        else if (!testTokens.nextToken().matches(">|<|>=|<=|=="))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperatorException();
        }

        //here is where I try to take the relational operator
        //and dump it into optok, after all the previous input
        //has been validated, but it doesnt work :(
        while (testTokens.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            tok = testTokens.nextToken();

            if (tok.matches("<|>|>=|<=|=="))
            {
                optok = tok;
            }
        }

    }//end evaluateTokens
```

And here is the `actionPerformed()` of my program that reacts when the user types their query into the `TextField` and presses the **`GO!`** `JButton` :

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
    {
        if (ev.getSource() == goBtn)
        {
            input = queryFld.getText();

            try
            {
                detectUserInput(input);
                countTokens(input);
                evaluateTokens(input);
            }
            catch (MissingInputException mie)
            {
                errorFld.setText("Enter an expression");
                queryFld.setText("");
                System.err.println(mie);
                mie.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IncorrectFormatException ife)
            {
                errorFld.setText("Too few terms");
                queryFld.setText("");
                System.err.println(ife);
                ife.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IllegalStartOfQueryException isqe)
            {
                errorFld.setText("Word REPORT expected");
                queryFld.setText("");
                System.err.println(isqe);
                isqe.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (InvalidSelectorException ise)
            {
                errorFld.setText("Selector must be ALL");
                queryFld.setText("");
                System.err.println(ise);
                ise.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (InvalidQualifierException iqe)
            {
                errorFld.setText("Qualifier error - keyword WHERE missing");
                queryFld.setText("");
                System.err.println(iqe);
                iqe.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (InvalidLValueException ilve)
            {
                errorFld.setText("Invalid query. quality, numInStock, "
                                + "or basePrice expected");
                queryFld.setText("");
                System.err.println(ilve);
                ilve.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperatorException ioe)
            {
                errorFld.setText("InvalidOperatorException. < <= > >= == expected");
                queryFld.setText("");
                System.err.println(ioe);
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }//end actionPerformed
}//end ButtonHandler
```

I apologize if this seems trivial, but i'm having a really hard time figuring it out for some reason. I appreciate any input or suggestions. If i'm missing any info needed please let me know and i'll add it asap. Also, here are the instructions for this segment:

*11) Now, focus on the evaluateAll method. Get the next token. It should be any one of 3 words:
“basePrice” or “quality” or “numInStock” . If it is not, place the message “Invalid query, quality, numInStock or basePrice expected. If is one of those 3 words, you expect a relational operator, so get the next token, but save it in a new String, call it optok. If it is not a correct operator, place the message “invalid query,
You now have two Strings: token which is either “basePrice” or “quality” or “numInStock” and an optok which is one of the 5 relational operators listed above.*

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post a stacktrace, so I'm guessing you're not having an exception, and reading from your code I'm trying to understand what could be happening .. so I might be wrong.

It seems to me that you are using a tokenizer. A tokenizer is like a stream, once you call nextToken() it returns the token, and unless you save it somewhere the next call to nextToken() will make the previous one not accessible.

So, where you make :

```
    else if (!testTokens.nextToken().matches("quality|numInStock|basePrice"))
    {
        throw new InvalidLValueException();
    }
    else if (!testTokens.nextToken().matches(">|<|>=|<=|=="))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperatorException();
    }
```

You are consuming the tokens. As a result, when you get to the while :

```
while (testTokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
```

All the tokens are consumed, so it will not iterate here.

You should instead save your tokens in variables, so that you can both check and the use them :

```
    StringTokenizer testTokens = new StringTokenizer(input, " ,");

    if (!testTokens.nextToken().equalsIgnoreCase("report"))
    {
        throw new IllegalStartOfQueryException();
    }
    else if (!testTokens.nextToken().equalsIgnoreCase("all"))
    {
        throw new InvalidSelectorException();
    }
    else if (!testTokens.nextToken().equalsIgnoreCase("where"))
    {
        throw new InvalidQualifierException();
    }

    // TODO here i use local variables, since you need to use these outside this method,
    // maybe use class fields or whatever else
    String subject = testTokens.nextToken();
    String opttok = testTokens.nextToken();

    if (!subject.matches("quality|numInStock|basePrice"))
    {
        throw new InvalidLValueException();
    }
    else if (!opttok.matches(">|<|>=|<=|=="))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperatorException();
    }

    // done, now you have opttok and subject
```

Comment: You know, I had a sneaking suspicion that may be the case, but for whatever reason I ignored it. Thanks! I've never done anything like this before so i'm kind of learning on the fly. I appreciate your input!